# Autohotkey - Different commands when different programs are active

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a script that when clicking "SHIFT+ALT+I" it sends a particular command when Microsft Word is active and another command if Microsoft PowerPoint is Active (both programs are running at the same time).

The code should be something like:

```
"if Microsoft Word is open"
+!i::
MouseMove, 300,50,0
MouseClick, left

"if Microsoft Powerpoint is open"
+!i::
MouseMove, 600,100,0
MouseClick, left
```

Is there any (easy) way of doing that?

Comment: See [Window specific hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite straightforward.

First off:
The structure you propose is possible, but not with a standard hotkey trigger. You *can* have a timer running which checks if a window is open and that then detects keypresses and then takes action. Or you can indeed use what @user already linked to.
I would consider it more neat and efficiënt to have one hotkey trigger a window check and then take action accordingly.

The code would then look like:

```
+!i::
IfWinActive, Microsoft Word
{
MouseMove, 300,50,0
MouseClick, left
}

IfWinActive, Microsoft Powerpoint
{
MouseMove, 600,100,0
MouseClick, left
}

Return
```

Do note that this function checks the window title, so there has in this example to be "Microsoft Word" literally in the window title. Read up on this function here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way of defining application-specific hotkeys

**Define F1 macros conditional on active window:**

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2     ; All #If statements match anywhere in title

#IfWinActive Microsoft Word
  F1:: MsgBox F1 pressed in Word
#IfWinActive Notepad
  F1:: MsgBox F1 pressed in Notepad
#IfWinActive
  F1:: MsgBox F1 pressed elsewhere
```